# How to secure my mail in iOS?

Tags: ios, email, encryption, privacy

Can you please advise what is the best application for email encryption using iPhones and iPads?

Comment: [related: Email encryption options on an iPhone](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99935/55266)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of security you are looking for. For PGP, some options, as explained in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/what-are-some-encryption-options-for-iphone-1487231923), are iPGMail and oPenGP. If you are looking for a simpler option, in which you don't want to rely on the PGP web of trust, then you can use S/MIME in the stock mail app with little effort. The linked article explains the easiest way to do this on iOS.